# Pandas applymap function does not format numbers

Tags: pandas, format-string

I am running this inside the code lab, to format string to 2 decimal points. However, it does not work. What is wrong please? I am in Colab.

When I issue the following:

```
format = lambda x: '%.2f' % x
frame.applymap(format)  # applies to every single entry
```

I get

```
            b          d            e
Utah    0.950857    -0.472254   -0.109456
Ohio    -0.738897   0.218620    -0.982334
Texas   0.400049    0.412557    -0.262711
Oregon  1.130821    0.236745    1.921072
```

However, when I issue

```
frame['e'].map(format)
```

It returns correct result.

```
Utah       0.27
Ohio       1.61
Texas      0.26
Oregon    -0.74
Name: e, dtype: object
```

Here is the my execution. [image: link]

Comment: this works in my computer... `frame=frame.applymap(format)`?

Comment: No on my end! Please see the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are they strings as you've indicated?  If not, you can always use `frame.round(2)` on a `pandas` df.

If it is a string, you could try first converting the column to float and then applying the round function.

```
for col in frame.columns:
    frame[col] = frame[col].astype(float)
frame = frame.round(2)
```